# phpexcel not hiding column

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<?php

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = './source/marks.xls';  //using this in the meantime. Will replace later with an import feature

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);


echo '<hr />';

$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setVisible(false);
echo '<table>' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
echo '<tr>' . "\n";
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,

foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
}
echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
?>
```

Please am working with this code for a school work. everything works well except the

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setVisible(false);
```

which is suppose to hide column D.

Function of the code is to read the individual marks from an excel file and display it in html view. eg.

> [image: snapshot of results]

My aim is to hide the **Index no** column from displaying in the html view. **"removeColumn('A')" works** but i am doing a search with the values in column A. So just want to hide that column.

Comment: The only displaying that you're doing is with ___your own code___ (those iterator loops) and you're not checking column visibility at all.... hiding columns/rows works with PHPExcel's own writers, but will only work with your code if you explicitly test for it

Comment: Test the $cell address to see if it's  in column D, and don't display it

Comment: k. tried the hide column with the "01simple-download-xls" and its hiding the column.
The problem is how i framed the question. I am editing the question to explain my self well.

Comment: The answer is still the same.... "Test the $cell address... and don't display it" if you don't want to see it.... `foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) { if ($cell->getColumn() !== 'A') {
echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
} }`

Comment: thanks a lot. it works.

Comment: @MarkBaker
is it possible to select a particular row based on a search and still hide the column. Say "index no." is in column A, search for index 11002, return that row and hide the "index no." column after that.